# need to send mutipart/form data includes text fields in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing this on loginsubmit but not working.

```
this.loginsubmit = function (logindata) {

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("grant_type", logindata.grant_type);
    fd.append("username", logindata.username);
    fd.append("password", logindata.password);

    $http.post("url", fd,
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("my-trusted-client:"), 'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
      }
    ).then(function (updateStatus, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(updateStatus);
    });
  }
```

Comment: what is not working? what you need, pls elaborate more.

Comment: I see no reason for a multipart request. Why not using `application/json` content type?